# How can I get real frame from Autolayout

Tags: ios

I create a view(width:600) with xib and put a UIScrollView(margin both left and right 20) in it. I want to get the scrollView's width in code but I get 560 instead. I'm new to AutoLayout and really want some help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the width? add some code. For example, if you are trying to get the width just after you load the nib, it will give you the width based on the size in the xib (600 - 40). You need to add the view, add constraints, and do 'layoutIfNeeed' on the container view, so it will update the layout by your constraints. Just add some code..

Answer (score 0):

It's all a question of *when* you get the scroll view's width in code. `viewDidLoad` is too soon. `viewDidAppear` would be okay. But the best time is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because that's when layout has been performed and the scroll view's width has been set.

Comment: However, you should also ask yourself why you want this information. You are using auto layout, so in theory everything should be done with constraints relative to other things. You shouldn't need to know the numeric value of the scroll view's width; the fact that you are asking for this info is a "bad smell".

Comment: I want to add some buttons into the scroll view, but the button's width is based on the text in it, so I just add buttons with code rather than xib, that's why I really want the scroll view's width

Comment: I'm totally with you, but read what I said. The button width can be based on the text within it, or it can be based on the width of its superview, or it can be based on something else, and you can arrange all of that _with autolayout constraints_ (in the nib). You yourself have said you are new to autolayout, so listen to someone who is _not_ new: _learn_ autolayout and _use_ it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and I will learn auto layout first before I can get my demo done

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your XIB and call `layoutIfNeeded`. At the next runloop cycle you will be able to see your actual frame size.